# Using Verilator with CMake when RTL uses a SV package

Tags: cmake, verilator

I´m trying to port a Verilator TB from Make to CMake. My CMakeLists looks like this:

```
add_executable(example ./src/my_tb.cpp)

list(APPEND rtl_sources ../rtl/some_pkg.sv ../rtl/some_module.sv ../rtl/top_core.sv)

verilate(example
  VERILATOR_ARGS -Wall --Wno-fatal --sv
  INCLUDE_DIRS "./src"
  SOURCES ${rtl_sources}
  TOP_MODULE top_core)
```

When I run this, the verilate command ignores the `TOP_MODULE` parameter and creates `"Vsome_pkg.h"` and related files. This means that my cpp TB will not build, because it expects to include `"Vtop_core.h"`.

I cannot move `top_core.sv`to the head of the filelist because it uses the package; the filelist needs to reflect the RTL dependencies, as far as I can tell, otherwise verilate fails.

In the Make version of mt TB, I invoke verilate with `--top top_core` and it all works just fine.

My verilator version is 5.018 and the Verilator reference documentation I´m using is for 5.017.
Also, I made a few experiments and `TOP_MODULE` fails if I use a non-existent module name, so it definitely is being read by the verilate command; yet somehow it´s being ignored.

I am a complete newcomer to CMake (I started the port today because I need to improve my TB with C++ libraries that in practice demand CMake) so I am pretty sure I am missing something basic.

Any help in spotting what I´m missing will be greatly appreciated!

**SUMMARY:**
I expected the verilate command to use my TOP_MODULE argument and generate "Vtop_core.h" and related files.

Instead, it apparently ignored TOP_MODULE and used the first element of SOURCES as top module.

**UPDATE**:
I just noticed that the executed command line for verilate looks like this:

```
Verilator command: "/ucrt64/bin/verilator_bin.exe --compiler gcc --prefix Vsome_pkg 
--Mdir [...]/build/CMakeFiles/example.dir/Vsome_pkg.dir 
--make cmake --top top_core --cc 
-y ./src -Wall --Wno-fatal 
../rtl/some_pkg.sv ../rtl/some_module.sv ../rtl/top_core.sv"
```

(newlines added for readability)

So the `--top` argument is included in the command, but it can´t override the `--Mdir` and `--prefix` arguments.
More comments to follow as I do a few trials...

**FURTHER UPDATE**

If I add this to my verilate command

```
PREFIX Vtop_core
```

...then the whole thing works; verilate creates the Vtop_core.h and related files and the build now fails for a different and probably unrelated reason.

So this change fixes my problem. But it looks kinda hacky.

I´ll do a few more trials and will auto-respond this question later on, but if anyone can shed any light on this, it will help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding parameter `PREFIX Vtop_core` to the verilate command fixes the issue.

I am pretty sure this is not the canonic way to use SV packages in a CMake-enabled Verilator TB but it works.